# Add fields to SELECT *

Tags: sql, oracle

I can do

```
SELECT *
SELECT 1 as t
```

But this

```
SELECT *, 1 as t
SELECT 1 as t, *
```

give me error :

> expression is missing
>   [image]

Is there a work around to add additional columns or have to include every field name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use table alias:

```
SQL> select 1 as t from dual;

         T
----------
         1

SQL> select *, 1 as t from dual;
select *, 1 as t from dual
        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL> select d.*, 1 as t from dual d;         --> this! "d."

D          T
- ----------
X          1

SQL>
```

Comment: i am very surprised to find out that Oracle version 18 even does not support the tableless syntax  `SELECT
 a.n
FROM (
 VALUES(1), (2)
) AS a(n)`, from the SQL 92 standard.. Wasn't it Oracle which had alots off influence on the ANSI/ISO SQL standard in the past, or do i mix Oracle up for IBM now... Well i geuss support will not come soon they use `dual` in both Oracle database and MySQL for tableless selects..